# Camel - Producer Template Http4 Response Code

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-camel

I have a [producer template](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html) that invokes an [Http4 end point](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html). How can I get the http status response code (like 200, 201, etc) ?

```
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, GET);

producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders("https4://myhostname.com:443/myURL", null, headers, String.class);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this (slight permutation of the [Camel docu](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html)):

```
Exchange exchange = template.send("https4://myhostname.com:443/myURL", new Processor() {
  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, GET);
  }
});
Message out = exchange.getOut();
int responseCode = out.getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, Integer.class);
```

It might also work without passing the processor, since http4 default to GET if the body is empty.

Answer (score 2):

See this [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) :

It's in the header `Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE`